# Issue using protocol to connect two classes in swift language

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I use playground and try to get message "show : Hello" in below simple code. However, nothing shows, but there is no compiler error. I don't where the problem is.

```
protocol showSome{
   func show(str:String)
}
class client: showSome{
   var s: server?
   init(){
       s = server(str: "Hello", delegate: self)
   }    
   func setup(){
       let server = s!
       server.service()       
   }    
   func show(str: String) {
       println("show: \(str)")
   }
}
class server{
   let delegate: showSome?
   let str: String
   init(str: String, delegate: showSome){
       self.delegate = delegate
       self.str = str
   }
   func service(){
       let d = delegate!
       d.show(str)
   }
}

var c = client()
c.setup()
```

Comment: println in playground does nothing? do you have timeline open?

Comment: yeah, nothing happened. I guess maybe I need a more stable version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me. You have to open the timeline if you are in a playground to see the output go `println()`

[image: open timeline]

btw: by conventions class names are using CamelCase with an initial big letter.

Answer (score 0):

The Playground doesn't display the output from `println`. Open the Assistant Editor via the View > Assistant Editor menu, and you should see it.

Comment: Yeah, I know this, I tried to view it in console, but nothing appears.

Answer (score 0):

Your class - "server" - has the same name as your client's variable. So I'm not sure what happens when you say

```
   s = server(str: "Hello", delegate: self)
```

<snip>

```
   let server = s!
   server.service()
```

I changed the names of your classes to ***S***erver & ***C***lient and it works as expected.

Comment: I think it does not matter, but appreciate it that you give an answer. I don't know who vote down your comment, but I vote it back for your participation!

Comment: variable names can't be the problem as those get substituted with otter identifiers during compilation. and naming a variable like a class name is fine — but confusing — in any language I know.